# Managing multiple nodes with Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I know that using knife I can remotely bootstrap a target node. However in case of a large cluster , say around 50 nodes , I don't  want to run bootstrap command manually for each and every node. How and where can I specify the mapping between each of the node and their runlist and avoid running bootstrap command through knife manually for each node?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://github.com/opscode/chef-metal

Comment: More information about how your cluster looks like might be helpful. Can you change the image that is started by the machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include Chef and the configuration (`client.rb` and validation certificate) for `chef-client` in your image. Nodes will register themselves once `chef-client` runs for the first time.

Comment: An alternative to baking chef into the image is to use cloud-init (supported by most cloud like Amazon and Openstack). See: http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#install-and-run-chef-recipes,  http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/user-data.html and http://devops.com/blogs/bootstrapping-chef-or-whatever-for-autoscaled-ec2-instances/